# gimp-plugin cannot find gtk/gtk.h

Tags: gtk, plugin, gimp

I am trying to install a plugin for gimp and am getting this gtk error, no matter what I do, I've installed just about every gtk-2.0 / gtk-3.0 devel and other packages and still it is a no go, so I edited the source files, bimp-gui.c , bimp-gui.h and still I can not get it to work. help, anyone?

```
%userx@voided gimp-plugin-bimp-1.16>$sudo find /usr/include -type f -name gtk.h
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h
```

here are the errors

```
%userx@voided gimp-plugin-bimp-1.16>$make
sh: pkg-config: command not found
No output from 'pkg-config --cflags gimpui-2.0'
which gimptool-2.0 && which pcre-config && \
gcc -o ./bin/bimp -Wall -O2 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-parentheses src/*.c src/manipulation-gui/*.c   -lpcre -lm -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED
/usr/bin/gimptool-2.0
/usr/bin/pcre-config
src/bimp-gui.c:5:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

so I went into that file and added this commenting out the

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

then added this

```
#include "/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h"
```

then it gave me this... still no go.

```
%userx@voided gimp-plugin-bimp-1.16>$make
sh: pkg-config: command not found
No output from 'pkg-config --cflags gimpui-2.0'
which gimptool-2.0 && which pcre-config && \
gcc -o ./bin/bimp -Wall -O2 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-parentheses src/*.c src/manipulation-gui/*.c   -lpcre -lm -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED
/usr/bin/gimptool-2.0
/usr/bin/pcre-config
In file included from src/bimp-gui.c:5:0:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:32:21: fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gdk/gdk.h>
```

I do not have a just

```
/usr/include/gtk/gtk.h
```

in my system. Is there such a thing as pre-gtk-2.0 to get a header for that. if yes then it has to be really outdated

oh yes this is the make line

```
make: 
which gimptool-2.0 && which pcre-config && \
gcc -o ./bin/bimp -Wall -O2 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-parentheses  src/*.c src/manipulation-gui/*.c $(GIMPARGS) $(PCREARGS) -lm -DGIMP_DISABLE_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key message is:

> sh: pkg-config: command not found

You need to install `pkgconfig` package in order to let your make file work properly